# Problems with setting background (Android Studio)

Tags: android, button, background

I'm having trouble with Android Studio.

When I place a button to my project, everything is fine. But when I set a background image (@drawable) and I try to run my application, I'm getting an error (unfortunately MyApp has stopped).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: 'I'm getting an error' is not a proper description of whatever error you're getting. Post your stacktrace.

Comment: I already post the error: unfortunately MyApp has stopped.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html